# Applying images to app from FireStore Storage

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I'm successfully able to upload images to FireStore Storage.

Now I'm trying to apply images stored in FireStore into people's user profiles on the app.

```
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFireStorage } from 'angularfire2/storage';

export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  routeParams;
  profilePicture: any = "../../assets/default-img.png"

  constructor(
  private afStorage: AngularFireStorage,
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) { }


  ngOnInit() 
  {
    this.routeParams = this.route.params.subscribe(
      params => {
          /*Update Variables here*/
          if (email.__email != "")
          {
            let path = "/" + email.__email + "/profile.png";
            this.profilePicture = this.afStorage.ref(path).getDownloadURL();
          }
      });
  }
}
```

All I want to do is retrieve the img from FireStore Storage and apply it to a person's profile picture.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url).

'getDownloadURL()' returns a promise, so you have to resolve that promise to actually get the data from the URL. If your HTML template is using `profilePicture`, you can just set the URL as the image source in `ngOnInit()`:

```
this.afStorage.ref(path).getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
  var img = document.getElementById('myimg');
  img.src = url;
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle any errors
});
```

Comment: I run the code and this returns an error.
first it says "Property 'then' does not exist in type Observable." I then add '.toPromise()' in between getDownloadURL() and .then to remove this error. But the code still doesn't work as the catch error returns [object object] as the error